# Visual Studio 2010 debugger visualizer for Qt image types?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, qt, qimage

Is there a VS 2010 debugger visualizer for Qt's image types (`QImage`, `QPixmap`, etc), similar to [this one for System.Drawing.Image](http://victorhurdugaci.com/projects/vsimagevisualizer/)? I glanced through [this article](http://www.pchenry.com/Home/tabid/36/EntryId/188/Visual-Studio-Debugger-Visualizers-are-VERY-cool-You-gotta-check-this-out.aspx) detailing the steps required to write such a visualizer, but I can't figure out if it's even possible to make one for `QImage` et al.

Comment: You can use [ImageWatch](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/imagewatchhelp/imagewatchhelp.htm) on VS11 and up. While it does not currently support Qt's image types out of the box, it's very easy to add new types. Unfortunately, I know of no equivalent addon for VS10.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any. There isn't in QtCreator, neither in the QT VS Add-in.

Comment: What about the second part of the question? Do you know if it is possible to write a custom visualizer for this, as [described here](http://www.pchenry.com/Home/tabid/36/EntryId/188/Visual-Studio-Debugger-Visualizers-are-VERY-cool-You-gotta-check-this-out.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

There is one in Qt Creator (Right click on a QImage entry in the Locals and Expression View, Change Local Display Format to "Displayed", but that works only with GDB and LLDB as debugging backend, not with CDB.